# What does AND 0xFF do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In the following code:

```
short = ((byte2 << 8) | (byte1 & 0xFF))
```

What is the purpose of `& 0xFF`? Because sometimes, I see the above code written as:

```
short = ((byte2 << 8) | byte1)
```

And that seems to work fine too.

Comment: Is byte1 of type `uint8_t`?

Comment: Then I guess it's only "just to be sure". Probably whoever wrote it was trying to be safe just in case someone changes the type of `byte1`, which seems quite likely because `byte2` already is not 8-bits (otherwise `byte2 << 8` is 0)

Comment: Sorry, `byte2 << 8` works even if `byte2` is an 8 bit type. By default expressions always work as `int`. The compiler sees implicitly the expression as `((int)byte2) << ((int)8)`

Comment: btw, `short` is a reserved word and can not be used as variable name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Anding an integer with `0xFF` leaves only the least significant byte. For example, to get the first byte in a `short s`, you can write `s & 0xFF`. This is typically referred to as "masking". If `byte1` is either a single byte type (like `uint8_t`) or is already less than 256 (and as a result is all zeroes except for the least significant byte) there is no need to mask out the higher bits, as they are already zero.

See <strike>tristopia</strike>Patrick Schlüter's answer below when you may be working with signed types. When doing bitwise operations, I recommend working only with unsigned types.

Answer (score 55):

if `byte1` is an 8-bit integer type then it's pointless - if it is more than 8 bits it will essentially give you the last 8 bits of the value:

```
    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
 &  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    -------------------------------
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 30):

The danger of the second expression comes if the type of `byte1` is `char`. In that case, some implementations can have it `signed char`, which will result in sign extension when evaluating.

```
signed char byte1 = 0x80;
signed char byte2 = 0x10;

unsigned short value1 = ((byte2 << 8) | (byte1 & 0xFF));
unsigned short value2 = ((byte2 << 8) | byte1);

printf("value1=%hu %hx\n", value1, value1);
printf("value2=%hu %hx\n", value2, value2);
```

will print

```
value1=4224 1080     right
value2=65408 ff80    wrong!!
```

I tried it on gcc v3.4.6 on Solaris SPARC 64 bit and the result is the same with `byte1` and `byte2` declared as `char`.

TL;DR

The masking is to avoid implicit sign extension.

*EDIT*: I checked, it's the same behaviour in C++.

*EDIT2*: As requested explanation of sign extension.
Sign extension is a consequence of the way C evaluates expressions. There is a rule in C called [promotion rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). C will implicitly cast all small types to `int` before doing the evaluation. Let's see what happens to our expression:

```
unsigned short value2 = ((byte2 << 8) | byte1);
```

`byte1` is a variable containing bit pattern 0xFF. If `char` is `unsigned` that value is interpreted as 255, if it is `signed` it is -1. When doing the calculation, C will extend the value to an `int` size (16 or 32 bits generally). This means that if the variable is `unsigned` and we will keep the value 255, the bit-pattern of that value as `int` will be 0x000000FF. If it is `signed` we want the value -1 which bit pattern is 0xFFFFFFFF. The sign was extended to the size of the tempory used to do the calculation.
And thus or-ing the temporary will yield the wrong result.

On x86 assembly it is done with the `movsx` instruction (`movzx` for the zero extend). Other CPU's had other instructions for that (6809 had `SEX`).

Comment: +1 for the warning, but I do not understand why or what is "sign extension", can you edit with a simple explaination?

Comment: Here a succinct explanation. You should look up the link I put there to learn more about the promotion rules of C as it is a very important point that people, even seasoned programmers, get wrong about the language.

Comment: Isn't 0xFFFFFFFF = -1? -128 would be 0xFFFFFF80.

Comment: You're right. Corrected EDIT2 section. Signed interpretation of 0xFF is -1 not -128. So the 0xFFFFFFFF is right, it is -1.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your `byte1` is a byte(8bits), When you do a bitwise AND of a byte with 0xFF, you are getting the same byte.

So `byte1` is the same as `byte1 & 0xFF`

Say `byte1` is `01001101` , then `byte1 & 0xFF = 01001101 & 11111111 = 01001101 = byte1`

If byte1 is of some other type say integer of 4 bytes, bitwise AND with 0xFF leaves you with least significant byte(8 bits) of the byte1.

Answer (score 5):

The `byte1 & 0xff` ensures that only the 8 least significant bits of `byte1` can be non-zero.

if `byte1` is already an unsigned type that has only 8 bits (e.g., `char` in some cases, or `unsigned char` in most) it won't make any difference/is completely unnecessary.

If `byte1` is a type that's signed or has more than 8 bits (e.g., `short`, `int`, `long`), and any of the bits except the 8 least significant is set, then there will be a difference (i.e., it'll zero those upper bits before `or`ing with the other variable, so this operand of the `or` affects only the 8 least significant bits of the result).

Comment: No, see my answer above. If the type of `byte1` is `char` or `signed char` it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

it clears the all the bits that are not in the first byte

Answer (score 0):

`& 0xFF` by itself only ensures that if bytes are longer than 8 bits (allowed by the language standard), the rest are ignored.

> And that seems to work fine too?

If the result ends up greater than `SHRT_MAX`, you get undefined behavior. In that respect both will work equally poorly.