# Byte array to Hex string conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, bitcoin, data-conversion

I have a byte array of the form `[4,-101,122,-41,-30,23,-28,3,..]` which I want to convert in the form `6d69f597b217fa333246c2c8`
I'm using below function

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
  return bytes.map(function(byte) {
    return (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
  }).join('')
}
```

which is giving me a string of the same form but I suspect that it's not an efficient conversion because the hex string is bit shorter than expected. I think translating should get "0a10a6dc".
Please tell me if I'm wrong or is this a right conversion but maybe I'm not using the right byte array

byte array `4,-127,45,126,58,-104,41,-27,-43,27,-35,100,-50,-77,93,-16,96,105,-101,-63,48,-105,49,-67,110,111,26,84,67,-89,-7,-50,10,-12,56,47,-49,-42,-11,-8,-96,-117,-78,97,-105,9,-62,-44,-97,-73,113,96,23,112,-14,-62,103,-104,90,-14,117,78,31,-116,-7`

Corresponding conversion `4812d7e3a9829e5d51bdd64ceb35df060699bc1309731bd6e6f1a5443a7f9ceaf4382fcfd6f5f8a08bb261979c2d49fb771601770f2c267985af2754e1f8cf9`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code. I changed the variables before posting but now I'm using the original code

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are missing the padding in the hex conversion. You'll want to use

```
function toHexString(byteArray) {
  return Array.from(byteArray, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('')
}
```

so that each byte transforms to exactly two hex digits. Your expected output would be `04812d7e3a9829e5d51bdd64ceb35df060699bc1309731bd6e6f1a5443a7f9ce0af4382fcfd6f5f8a08bb2619709c2d49fb771601770f2c267985af2754e1f8cf9`

Comment: @DavidCallanan grantpatternson was commenting on an old version of the answer, where I had used `byteArray.map` instead of `Array.from`

Comment: Same thing, but in a more compact form: `const toHexString = byteArray => Array.from(byteArray, byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')`

Comment: What is the `& 0xFF` for?

Comment: @Lance It casts the `byte` to an integer between 0 and 255. This is not necessary if the array elements already are unsigned octets ("bytes"), but e.g. the OP has signed integers.

Answer (score 12):

Using `map()` won't work if the input is of a type like `Uint8Array`: the result of `map()` is also `Uint8Array` which can't hold the results of string conversion.

```
function toHexString(byteArray) {
  var s = '0x';
  byteArray.forEach(function(byte) {
    s += ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  });
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Warning: It's getting "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".

Answer (score 8):

Since this is the first Google hit for "js byte to hex" and I needed some time to understand the function of Bergi, I rewrote the function and added some comments that made it easier for me to understand:

```
function byteToHex(byte) {
  // convert the possibly signed byte (-128 to 127) to an unsigned byte (0 to 255).
  // if you know, that you only deal with unsigned bytes (Uint8Array), you can omit this line
  const unsignedByte = byte & 0xff;

  // If the number can be represented with only 4 bits (0-15), 
  // the hexadecimal representation of this number is only one char (0-9, a-f). 
  if (unsignedByte < 16) {
    return '0' + unsignedByte.toString(16);
  } else {
    return unsignedByte.toString(16);
  }
}

// bytes is an typed array (Int8Array or Uint8Array)
function toHexString(bytes) {
  // Since the .map() method is not available for typed arrays, 
  // we will convert the typed array to an array using Array.from().
  return Array.from(bytes)
    .map(byte => byteToHex(byte))
    .join('');
}
```

- For more information about the `const unsignedByte = byte & 0xff`-part, check [What does AND 0xFF do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713102/what-does-and-0xff-do).
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is not available in every browser (e.g. not in IE11), check [How to convert a JavaScript Typed Array into a JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760643/how-to-convert-a-javascript-typed-array-into-a-javascript-array) for more information

The OP forgot to add the leading `0` for numbers that can be displayed with only 4 bits.

Answer (score 7):

A more concise and performant (see https://jsperf.com/byte-array-to-hex-string) alternative using Array.reduce():

```
function toHexString(byteArray) {
  return byteArray.reduce((output, elem) => 
    (output + ('0' + elem.toString(16)).slice(-2)),
    '');
}
```

(Also without "& 0xFF" because in my opinion if an array is passed in that contains values larger than 255, the output should be messed up, so that the user can more easily see that their input was wrong.)

Comment: Note that the `& 0xFF` might be necessary if the byteArray contains signed bytes that go from -128 to 127 instead of 0 to 255.

Comment: I'm surprised this is more performant, because it looks like its runtime is quadratic in the length of the byte array. Did you only try it on small arrays (the jsperf link is dead, BTW)? Or is javascript really smart about re-using the `output` location on each iteration of the `reduce`?

Answer (score 7):

All of the previous solutions work but they all require the creation of many strings and concatenation and slicing of the created strings. I got thinking there has to be a better way to go about it now that there are typed arrays. I originally did this using node and then commented out the lines that use Buffer and changed them to TypedArrays so it would work in a browser too.

It's more code but it's significantly faster, at least in the quick jsperf (no longer working) I put together. The string manipulation version in the accepted answer performed 37000 ops/sec while the code below managed 317000 ops/sec. There is a lot of hidden overhead in creating string objects.

```
function toHexString (byteArray) {
  //const chars = new Buffer(byteArray.length * 2);
  const chars = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length * 2);
  const alpha = 'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 10;
  const digit = '0'.charCodeAt(0);

  let p = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
      let nibble = byteArray[i] >>> 4;
      chars[p++] = nibble > 9 ? nibble + alpha : nibble + digit;
      nibble = byteArray[i] & 0xF;
      chars[p++] = nibble > 9 ? nibble + alpha : nibble + digit;    
  }

  //return chars.toString('utf8');
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chars);
}
```

Comment: pretty much all modern browsers support typed arrays (even IE 10 & 11).

Comment: if the input array is signed then this line `let nibble = byteArray[i] >>> 4` needs to be changed to `let nibble = byteArray[i] >>> 4 & 0xF;`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, A simpler solution with Typescript:

```js
const convertHashToHex = (value: TypedArray | number[]) : string => {
  return value.map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
}
```

JS version:

```js
const convertHashToHex = (value) => {
  return value.map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
}
```

Comment: And the reverse of this? convertHexToHash please? :)

Comment: That is not related with the original question, but if you open it, I would be happy to respond

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the hex conversion with the appropriate number of leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

When converting a byte array to a hex array, we have to consider how they can be signed numbers. If so, we gotta convert them to decimal numbers first. [signed numbers to decimal conversion](http://sandbox.mc.edu/%7Ebennet/cs110/tc/tctod.html#:%7E:text=If%20it%20is%20negative%2C%20make,and%20give%20its%20decimal%20equivalent.). Then, we can use the `.toString(16)` method to convert it to hex.

```js
const hexArr = byteArr.map((byte) => {
    if (byte < 0) {
      byte = -((byte ^ 0xff) + 1); //converting 2s complement to a decimal number
    }
    //add padding at the start to ensure it's always 2 characters long otherwise '01' will be '1'
    return byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cross-browser solution for ArrayBuffer:

```
    function buf2hex(buffer) {
        var u = new Uint8Array(buffer),
            a = new Array(u.length),
            i = u.length;
        while (i--) // map to hex
            a[i] = (u[i] < 16 ? '0' : '') + u[i].toString(16);
        u = null; // free memory
        return a.join('');
    };
```

Answer (score -5):

If running on Nodejs

just use Buffer.toString('base64')

```
crypto.randomBytes(byteLength).toString('base64')
```