# Javascript encoder problem with format and HEX

Tags: javascript, json, hex, encode, lorawan

I am working on an encoder for LoRaWAN with JavaScript. I receive this field of data:

```
{“header”: 6,“sunrise”: -30,“sunset”: 30,“lat”: 65.500226,“long”: 24.833547}
```

And I need to encode in an hex message, my code is:

```
var header = byteToHex(object.header);
var sunrise =byteToHex(object.sunrise);
var sunset = byteToHex(object.sunset);
var la = parseInt(object.lat100,10);
var lat = swap16(la);
var lo = parseInt(object.long100,10);
var lon = swap16(lo);
var message={};
if (object.header === 6){
    message = (lon)|(lat<<8);
    bytes = message;
}
return hexToBytes(bytes.toString(16));
```

Functions byteToHex / swap16 defined as:

```
function byteToHex(byte) {
    var unsignedByte = byte & 0xff;
    if (unsignedByte < 16) {
        return ‘0’ + unsignedByte.toString(16);
    } else {
        return unsignedByte.toString(16);
    }
}

function swap16(val) {
    return ((val & 0xFF) << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

Testing it with return message = lon produces B3 09 in hex.
Testing it with message = lon | lat <<8 return 96 BB 09 but result I am looking for is 96 19 B3 09 (composing lon + lat ).

Any tips? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt you receive the data in that format. Curly quotes are invalid there. Also in your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte array to Hex string conversion in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309988/byte-array-to-hex-string-conversion-in-javascript)

Comment: Since `lon` and `lat` are 16 bit numbers, you will lose information with `(lon)|(lat<<8)`. Did you mean `lon|(lat<<16)`?

Comment: @trincot copied from backend and it modified my response; fields are {
"header": 6,
"sunrise": -30,
"sunset": 30,
"lat": 65.500226,
"long": 24.833547
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using this code:

```
    var long = object.long;
    var lat = object.lat;
    lat = parseInt(lat*100,10);
    var la = swap16(lat);
    la = la.toString(16);
    long = parseInt(long*100,10);
    var lon = swap16(long);
    lon = lon.toString(16);
    var header = object.header;
    var result= la;
    result+= lon;
    result= result.toString(16);
    bytes = hexToBytes(result);
  }
  }
  return bytes;
```

Now response is:

```
// encoded payload:
96 19 B3 09
```